# Duplicate files copied in APK error_prone/Annotations.gwt.xml in interactivemedia

Tags: android, build.gradle

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDevDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK error_prone/Annotations.gwt.xml
>       File1: /Users/manmohansingh/.android/build-cache/c5c673e638724b8a150c9a07f761f05b8fef0253/output/jars/classes.jar
>       File2: /Users/manmohansingh/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.ads.interactivemedia.v3/interactivemedia/3.6.0/76bc1544c67335c4bb38631001fd05a3e70004e4/interactivemedia-3.6.0.jar

Comment: i have a same issue :{

Answer (score 19):

After struggling of three hours got this solution: Add these lines into

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'error_prone/Annotations.gwt.xml'
    exclude 'third_party/java_src/error_prone/project/annotations/Annotations.gwt.xml'
    exclude 'third_party/java_src/error_prone/project/annotations/Google_internal.gwt.xml'
}
```

FINAL :

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'

    exclude 'error_prone/Annotations.gwt.xml'
    exclude 'third_party/java_src/error_prone/project/annotations/Annotations.gwt.xml'
    exclude 'third_party/java_src/error_prone/project/annotations/Google_internal.gwt.xml'
}
```

Comment: While this works - and thanks a bunch for that - I would appreciate an explanation why for example a fresh new android project refuses to build without these types of additions to the build configuration. Preferably from someone actually developing android itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few methods to solve this problem:

1. Android Studio -> Build -> Clean project
2. Android Studio -> File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart ...
3. Need to add exclude in build.gradle file in android {} section:

   ```
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'error_prone/Annotations.gwt.xml'
        exclude 'third_party/java_src/error_prone/project/annotations/Annotations.gwt.xml'
        exclude 'third_party/java_src/error_prone/project/annotations/Google_internal.gwt.xml'
   ```

   }